# How to hide all the names when input is empty?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In the following code, when input is empty, all the names are shown. I want no name when the input field is empty.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">
<input ng-model="search.$"></label> <br>
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in names | filter : search">
    {{ x }}
  </li>
</ul>
</div>

<script>
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = [
        'Jani',
        'Carl',
        'Margareth',
        'Hege',
        'Joe',
        'Gustav',
        'Birgit',
        'Mary',
        'Kai'
    ];
});
</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a **[`ng-if`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)**

```
 <ul ng-if="search.$">
```

**DEMO**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">
<input ng-model="search.$"></label> <br>
<ul ng-if="search.$">
  <li ng-repeat="x in names | filter : search">
    {{ x }}
  </li>
</ul>
</div>

<script>
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = [
        'Jani',
        'Carl',
        'Margareth',
        'Hege',
        'Joe',
        'Gustav',
        'Birgit',
        'Mary',
        'Kai'
    ];
});
</script>
```

Comment: May I suggest adding a trim() and a length check? `<ul ng-if="search.$ && search.$.trim().length > 0">`

Comment: can you suggest some good source to learn angular for web development. I precisely want to create a search box for my website which will search for the results in my mongoDb and the server side language i am using is node.js

Answer (score 1):

Use  `ng-if`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">
<input ng-model="search.$"></label> <br>
<ul>
  <li ng-if="search.$" ng-repeat="x in names | filter : search">
    {{ x }}
  </li>
</ul>
</div>

<script>
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = [
        'Jani',
        'Carl',
        'Margareth',
        'Hege',
        'Joe',
        'Gustav',
        'Birgit',
        'Mary',
        'Kai'
    ];
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This Code it will help you

```
<script https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">
  <input ng-model="search"></input> <br>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in names | filter : search">
      {{ x }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script>
  angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {

    if ($scope.$$childHead.search == "") {
      $scope.names = [];
    } else {
      $scope.names = [
        'Jani',
        'Carl',
        'Margareth',
        'Hege',
        'Joe',
        'Gustav',
        'Birgit',
        'Mary',
        'Kai'
      ];
    }
  });
</script>

<!-- end snippet -->
```